# Filter array in PHP using SQL

Tags: php, sql

I don't know much about SQL. I'm trying to access this information to put it in a variable.

For example, I need to take the e-mails, the two values ​​and put them in a separate variable.

How do I make a filter to find these variables according to the email value?

```php
    $comissao_total = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_content FROM wp0l_posts WHERE id = 9029");
    print_r($comissao_total);
```

The return I get is something like this.

```php
Array( 
    [0] => 
    [post_content] => [
        ["Email","D\u00e9bito","Cr\u00e9dito","Identifica\u00e7\u00e3o do Vendedor"],
        ["abraaop739@gmail.com","725","0","jrexpress.soares2020@gmail.com"],  
        ["admilsondemorais@gmail.com","645.5","20",
             "ygor.carvalho.nascimento@gmail.com"],
        ["adriano_sena1985@hotmail.com","200","0","jhony96cesar@gmail.com"],
        ["agromasteragro@gmail.com","21591.2","3573.2",
             "ygor.carvalho.nascimento@gmail.com"]
    ] 
))
```

In this case it returns the array with all the data, but in fact I would need to get only the values, via email.

For example: If I want to filter the email `jrexpress.soares2020@gmail.com`, I need to receive 725 and 0 in two variables. Corresponding to this array `["abraaop739@gmail.com", "725", "0", "jrexpress.soares2020@gmail.com"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write yourself a function and loop thru the array with *foreach*

```php
<?php
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "";

// your input array
$yourArray['0']['post_content'] = Array( [
        ["Email","D\u00e9bito","Cr\u00e9dito","Identifica\u00e7\u00e3o do Vendedor"],
        ["abraaop739@gmail.com","725","0","jrexpress.soares2020@gmail.com"],  
        ["admilsondemorais@gmail.com","645.5","20","ygor.carvalho.nascimento@gmail.com"],
        ["adriano_sena1985@hotmail.com","200","0","jhony96cesar@gmail.com"],
        ["agromasteragro@gmail.com","21591.2","3573.2","ygor.carvalho.nascimento@gmail.com"]
    ] );

// your filter function
function filter($email){
  global $var1;
  global $var2;
  global $yourArray;
  foreach($yourArray['0']['post_content'][0] as $var){
    foreach($var as $val){
    if($val == $email){
        $var1 = $var['1'];
        $var2 = $var['2'];
      }
    }
  }
}

//calling the function
filter("jrexpress.soares2020@gmail.com");

// output
echo "<pre>";
echo "\$var1 = $var1 \n";
echo "\$var2 = $var2 \n";
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I managed to adapt it and get a sense of which way to go, thank you very much!